# When unsubscribe in email opt_out auto check

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

How can I do that when partner that received email pushes unsubscribe and then  op_out field in this partner form is automatically checked?

```xml
   <record id="partner_mass_mail_hetlita" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">Mass Mail Hetlita</field>
            <field name="model_id" model="ir.model" search="[('model', '=', 'res.partner')]"></field>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="email_to">${(object.email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(user.email or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">news</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
<p>Sveiki, ${object.name}</p>

<p>newsletter</p>

<div style="height: auto;width:450px; margin:0 auto;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:40px;">
    <a style="padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;border-radius: 6px;border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;background:#8A89BA;margin : 0 15px 0 0;text-decoration: none;color:#FFFFFF;" href="/massmailing/new-lead?db=${'dbname' in ctx and ctx['dbname'] or ''}&amp;partner_id=${object.id}&amp;partner_id.opt_out=${object._opt_out()}">Unsubscribe</a>
</div>
            ]]></field>
        </record>
```

method in res partner

```py
 @api.multi
    def _opt_out(self):
        self.opt_out = False
```

UPDATE

gettig error

```
Failed to render template <Template memory:7f73f9b31690> using values {'format_tz': <function <lambda> at 0x7f73f94accf8>, 'ctx': {u'lang': u'en_US', u'tz': False, u'uid': 1, u'active_model': u'mail.template', 'safe': False, u'params': {u'action': 640}, u'search_disable_custom_filters': True, u'active_ids': [15], u'template_id': 15, u'active_id': 15}, 'user': res.users(1,), 'object': res.partner(3886,)}
```